# In which sentence I asked about "use of electronic device"?

Tags: discussion

[Why do we not get shocked by neutral wire and how can it behave as it does?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/458361/why-do-we-not-get-shocked-by-neutral-wire-and-how-can-it-behave-as-it-does)

As you can see my question is about electric circuits and how they work/behave. I don't see I'm asking any use of electronic device but still closed.

Can you please explain?

Comment: I removed a paragraph mentioning the dimming of light. My edit also forced me to remove the `electricity` tag. I have voted to re open the question. Since an accepted and twice upvoted anwer exists and the answer looks reasonable.

Comment: @AJN thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 3):

Yes:

[image]

The question was closed because it's more about the use of how electronics work and not about electronic design. While asking about electronics is not explicitly off topic the question needs to be well documented and have proper research and be phrased more as a design question. For myself, I'm having a really hard time following the question and the paint plot (prefer a schematic, use the embedded circuit tool).

This type of question has already been asked:

[why neutral does not shock. how can a neutral be neutral in ac current?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/449300/why-neutral-does-not-shock-how-can-a-neutral-be-neutral-in-ac-current)

so I would think it's more of a duplicate.

Comment: Can the user delete the question (since an accepted answer exists?) Non re-opening and non deleting effectively locks the user out. :(

Comment: We can delete the question, but that does bring some 'unfairness' to the user that wrote an accepted answer. For those that have accepted answers with upvotes, I usually leave the question to be fair to those who answered.